# RubyMine - no run rails generator option under tools after cloning repository

Tags: rubymine

Whenever I create a project from existing files by cloning a repository, the options run rails script and run rails generators don't appear under tools.

It's like RubyMine doesn't recognize the project as a rails application. How do I solve this?

Comment: RubyMine looks at the existence of the "app" directory and the "config/routes.rb" file to detect an app as a Rails application. Do these exist in the directory that you have opened?

Comment: Yes, both of them exist.

Comment: Are you using Bundler? Did you get any messages from RubyMine about not being able to load the list of gems?

Comment: Nope, bundle install works just fine.

Comment: Found out what was wrong (see my answer). Thanks for the help yole :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accidentally the `.idea` folder was pushed to Git and then later pulled.

Removing `.idea` from the root of the project and restarting RubyMine solved the problem.